# Iterating through a JSON object after first level

Tags: python, json

I would like to print key and value on each line so it would be.
key1, value1 then key2, value2 etc

My current code prints:

```
The key and value are data = [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}]
```

instead of `"The key and value are key1 = value1"` etc

```
import json

jsonString = '{ "data": [ {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"} ] }'
jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

for key in jsonObject:
    value = jsonObject[key]
    print("The key and value are {} = {}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: `for key, value in jsonObject["data"][0].items():`

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I'm getting an error on the traceback

`value = jsonObject[key]
KeyError: 'key1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are iterating through the dictionary created by your JSON at a level too high. You can go inside the dictionary at key = 'data' by using jsonObject["data"], then iterate like you did.

```
for key in jsonObject["data"][0]:
    value = jsonObject["data"][0][key]
    print("The key and value are {} = {}".format(key, value))
```

You could even write this more concisely using the .items() built-in method for dictionaries:

```
for key,value in jsonObject["data"][0].items():
    print("The key and value are {} = {}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: Based on the second answer.
`for key,value in jsonObject["data"][0].items():`

After that's completed and wanted to move upwards automatically?
`for key,value in jsonObject["data"][1].items():`

Comment: You would do that if you have a list of dictionnaries inside your data.

Comment: you could write another fo loop around the existing code to deal with this: `for inner_dict in jsonObject["data"]:`, then use `inner_dict` instead of `jsonObject["data"][0]` inside the second for loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `data` (which is a list in your case) inside your JSON could contain more than one element :

```py
import json

jsonString = '{ "data": [ {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"} ] }'
jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

print("The keys and values are:")
for item in jsonObject["data"]:
    for key, value in item.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Will print:

```
The keys and values are:
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```